# Program does not contain main.server.ngfactory.ts after upgrading to Angular v9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I am having trouble with Angular 9 and universal. When upgraded to v9 and running npm run build:ssr script, it throws me an error:

Program does not contain ...src/src/main.server.ngfactory.ts

It worked in v8, but after upgrading core and cli, something went wrong. It works if running serve or build, but when wanna run SSR it doesn't work. I can also see that other devs have the same problem with it from posts on issues git -> angular/universal. The documents are very unclear what to do with @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader. Should we use it or not. As reading docs, when upgrading to v9, it removes it automatically, because it is deprecated. Anyway, error says like it needs it? Or I am wrong.

Here are some code snippets, my config files etc:

package json file:

```
{
  "name": "app-universal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run app-universal:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/app-universal/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run app-universal:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run app-universal:prerender"
  },
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  }
```

app.server.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

main.server.ts file:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

tsconfig.server.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app-server",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

server.ts file:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/app-universal/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app-angular": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app-angular/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app-angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app-angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app-angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app-angular/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app-angular:build",
            "serverTarget": "app-angular:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app-angular:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "app-angular:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app-angular:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "app-angular:server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"app-angular
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "app-angular-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app-angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app-angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "app-angular"
}
```

Here is my full stack trace with error:

```
> app-universal@0.0.0 build:ssr /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal
> ng build --prod && ng run app-universal:server:production

Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.

chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.28b264071c0a6503d0b4.js (polyfills) 36.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es5.d58c77c3e4e6875be71a.js (polyfills-es5) 129 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es2015.b90be8c0d934accf4a89.js (main) 1.12 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es5.b90be8c0d934accf4a89.js (main) 1.21 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es2015.373942d2a2bfd7c0992a.js (runtime) 2.33 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es5.373942d2a2bfd7c0992a.js (runtime) 2.33 kB [entry] [rendered]app-universal
chunk {5} 5-es2015.aa4d0b9984d3a16c4b30.js () 7.92 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} 5-es5.aa4d0b9984d3a16c4b30.js () 8.52 kB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6-es2015.84898a6e53a31813b9e4.js () 3.59 kB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6-es5.84898a6e53a31813b9e4.js () 4.06 kB  [rendered]
chunk {9} 9-es2015.802c953e13629d5d4d58.js () 31.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {9} 9-es5.802c953e13629d5d4d58.js () 32.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {8} 8-es2015.754ae391c85ccd4b25ed.js () 4.69 kB  [rendered]
chunk {8} 8-es5.754ae391c85ccd4b25ed.js () 5.19 kB  [rendered]
chunk {7} 7-es2015.7fffde32d1027b060b4a.js () 4.32 kB  [rendered]
chunk {7} 7-es5.7fffde32d1027b060b4a.js () 5.06 kB  [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.e3d326e6f5a9793facb9.css (styles) 199 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-03-29T11:19:52.719Z - Hash: 8c33a9ce794546362630 - Time: 41217ms
Hash: 7a6fe79632181b437acb
Time: 1326ms
Built at: 03/29/2020 13:20:00
  Asset      Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
main.js  1.75 KiB       0  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
chunk    {0} main.js (main) 28 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in Program does not contain "/Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/src/src/main.server.ngfactory.ts" - available files are /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2018.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.generator.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.proxy.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.reflect.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.sharedmemory.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.string.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.intl.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.typedarrays.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2018.asyncgenerator.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2018.asynciterable.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2018.intl.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2018.promise.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2018.regexp.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.esnext.intl.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.esnext.bigint.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/src/__ng_typecheck__.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/async_hooks.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/buffer.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/events/index.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/child_process.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/cluster.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/console.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/constants.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/crypto.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/dgram.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/dns.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/domain.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/events.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/fs.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/http.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/http2.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/https.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/inspector.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/module.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/net.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/os.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/path.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/perf_hooks.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/process.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/punycode.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/querystring.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/readline.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/repl.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/stream.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/string_decoder.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/timers.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/tls.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/trace_events.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/tty.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/url.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/v8.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/vm.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/worker_threads.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/zlib.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/base.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/ts3.2/fs.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/ts3.2/util.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/ts3.2/globals.d.ts, /Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/node_modules/@types/node/ts3.2/index.d.ts
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app-universal@0.0.0 build:ssr: `ng build --prod && ng run app-universal:server:production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app-universal@0.0.0 build:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dmdeveloper/.npm/_logs/2020-03-29T11_20_01_056Z-debug.log
```

Does anyone have the same problem or see something I am missing? As I said, it was working great before updating to new version. Any help would be most welcome!

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60431143/1160794

Comment: Please add your `server.ts` file

Comment: I edit my question, also edit package,json file, so u can see my scripts. Tanx!

Comment: That does look right. Could you add the exact error (with call stack) and your `angular.json` file?

Comment: There you go, angular.json fiel and stack trace error in full!

Comment: Can you try these replacements in `angular.json` file in the `server` section? Replace `"main": "src/main.server.ts",` with `"main": "main.server.ts",`and   replace`"tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"` with `"tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"`

Comment: I have tried. Stack error: An unhandled exception occurred: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/tsconfig.server.json'. Or if I just try for main.server.ts, error is:ERROR in multi ./main.server.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal/main.server.ts' in '/Users/dmdeveloper/app-universal-frontend-angular/app-universal'

Comment: Where are your main.server and tsconfig.server.json files located then? In your original error message, you  can see that the process is looking for something in `src/src`, hence why I asked to make these changes. And they match what i have win my files too

Comment: Yes, I get it. I feel confused too. Because they are under src directory. I can see in error that is looking for src/src, but there are no src/src directories, just src.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210531/discussion-between-david-and-dm-developing).

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is having the same issue, here is what worked for me. The main problem was in path for server.ts file.

Here is what happened: In angula.json in server section, I changed path for main, that is "main": 
`"server.ts", instead of main.server.ts.`

Second thing, in tsconfig.server.json,path was wrong: Now is

```
"files": [
"./main.server.ts",
"../server.ts"
],
```

Now, it builds browser and server and runs on port 4000!